# LocalSessionFactoryBean can't map package in jar file Spring 4

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

The sessionFactory, can't map package

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>com.env.recru.domain</value>
            <value>com.env.curric.domain</value>
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

In first package, work, but sencond has a package in one artifactId, call env-10.jar

- Project use Spring 4
- Hibernate 4
- Use maven manage dependency

Link of the [Reference](https://static.javadoc.io/org.springframework/spring-orm/4.2.1.RELEASE/org/springframework/orm/hibernate5/LocalSessionFactoryBean.html#setMappingJarLocations-org.springframework.core.io.Resource...-)

How to map jar in that sessionFactory?

Comment: How are you managing your dependencies in projects?

Comment: yes, dependency is correct

Comment: That's not what I asked for. I asked about how you're managing your dependencies. This is, are you using maven, gradle, ivy, ant, or the tools your IDE provides?

Comment: Use maven for manage

Comment: Ok then, please provide the pom.xml for both projects to see why your project cannot get the dependencies properly.

Comment: Projeject owner ready a dependency correct, that artifactyId has others class same Service and Repository and Controller componets spring, thats ok
in that test web access controller work.

Comment: Found the problem, i'm was used one method wrong in consult... CreateSQL query .. When use querConsult